# Как определить синтаксис этой конструкции?

Tags: синтаксис

Пример: Ты не знаешь, кто, пока ты тут сидишь, твою кашу съедает! Как правильно определяется синтаксис такого предложения? Можно ли так построить? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

*Ты не знаешь, кто, пока ты тут сидишь, твою кашу съедает*

Сложноподчинённое предложение с двумя придаточными, соединёнными между собой последовательно. При этом второе придаточное находится внутри первого: [- = ], (кто, (пока), ...).

Таких примеров СПП много, вполне корректная конструкция.